# getting control over a form been posted with Asp Net Mvc Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Ajax.BeginForm to post a form and the last event triggered before the form is sent is the onBegin event.

onBegin event is triggered after the form is serialized to be posted.
I need control over this form but I am not able to create my own submit event

ex.:

```
$('#myForm').submit()
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to manipulate the serialized form before it is sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js section that serialize form:

```
$("form[data-ajax=true]").live("submit", function (evt) {
    var clickInfo = $(this).data(data_click) || [];
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (!validate(this)) {
        return;
    }
    asyncRequest(this, {
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method || "GET",
        data: clickInfo.concat($(this).serializeArray())
    });
});
```